# Name of a document behind an HTML link?

Tags: php, python, html, http

I need to automatically download documents from Web pages (with a Python script). In the HTML pages, links look like this:

```
href="https://foo.bar/view.php?id=123456"
```

When I click on such a link in a Web browser, the Web browser opens the document with its correct name - for example: `document_1.pdf`.

However, when I download the same document with wget:

```
$ wget https://foo.bar/view.php?id=123456
```

I do get the correct document, but under a different name: `view.php@id=123456`

Now, the real name of the document (`document_1.pdf` in this example) appears nowhere in the HTML page. How can I get it?

If it's possible for a Web browser to get at the name of the document, it must be possible also for a script to do so, but how?

Comment: The file download server response contains the file name in [a header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628260/downloading-a-file-with-a-different-name-to-the-stored-name).

Comment: Yes, that's it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Resolved in comments:**
>
> ```
> The file download server response contains the file name in a header. – James
> ```